How do i hide all MDI children form until they are all loaded and arranged?
Here is how i add and arrange the forms based on their Tag:
public static void AddForm(Form parentForm, Form childForm, int tag)
        {
            childForm.MdiParent = parentForm;
            childForm.Tag = tag;
            childForm.Show();
        }
public static void ArrangeChildForms(Form parentForm)
        {
            int numberOfColumns = parentForm.MdiChildren.Length / 2 + parentForm.MdiChildren.Length % 2;
            int numberOfChildForms = parentForm.MdiChildren.Length;

            int availableWidth = parentForm.ClientSize.Width - 20;
            int availableHeight = parentForm.ClientSize.Height;

            int childFormWidth = availableWidth / numberOfColumns;
            int childFormHeight = availableHeight / 2;

            Form[] sortedChildren = parentForm.MdiChildren.OrderBy(child => (int)child.Tag).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildForms; i++)
            {
                Form child = sortedChildren[i];
                int row = i / numberOfColumns;
                int col = i % numberOfColumns;
                child.Left = col * childFormWidth;
                child.Top = row * childFormHeight;
                child.Width = childFormWidth;
                child.Height = childFormHeight;
            }
        }

Here is how i call the methods in container/parent form (called after parent form is fully loaded):
foreach (var (machine, i) in _lstMachine.Select((machine, i) => (machine, i)))
        {
            Form form = GetForm(machine.CommunicationType, machine.ID);
            AddForm(this, form, i);
        }
        ArrangeChildForms(this);

The problem is it shows the entire process of adding child forms and arranging them, but I want to hide all the child forms until they are arranged to their place. I've tried tinkering around the visibility of the forms, move the childForm.Show() from AddForm() to ArrangeChildForms(), use SuspendLayout() in the container but it doesn't work either. Hopefully I can get some insights about this problem.

Should be hard to do with MDI. If you don't need any specific MDI feature you might get something working with simply adding the childforms as Controls and not as MDI childs.
Changes to your code to add them as controls might look like this.
        public static void AddForm(Form parentForm, Form childForm, int tag)
        {
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            parentForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
            childForm.Tag = tag;
            childForm.Show();
        }

        public static void ArrangeChildForms(Form parentForm)
        {
            var forms = parentForm.Controls.OfType<Form>().OrderBy(child => (int)child.Tag).ToArray();

            int numberOfColumns = forms.Length / 2 + forms.Length % 2;
            int numberOfChildForms = forms.Length;

            int availableWidth = parentForm.ClientSize.Width - 20;
            int availableHeight = parentForm.ClientSize.Height;

            int childFormWidth = availableWidth / numberOfColumns;
            int childFormHeight = availableHeight / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildForms; i++)
            {
                Form child = forms[i];
                int row = i / numberOfColumns;
                int col = i % numberOfColumns;
                child.Left = col * childFormWidth;
                child.Top = row * childFormHeight;
                child.Width = childFormWidth;
                child.Height = childFormHeight;
            }
        }

If you still see a delay in showing the childform they might be doing something in their code path when showing like doing database request or something like that. THat needs then to be looked at individually.
